# How to audit the sharepoint search?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I want to audit the sharepoint searches using Sharepoint object model... how to do it?
using sharepoint object model how can i get the audited report for these searches.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What specific information do you need? SharePoint already comes with [Search Usage Reporting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262541.aspx).

You can track stuff like:
- Queries per day over the previous 30 days.
- Queries per month over the previous 12 months.
- Top queries over the previous 30 days.
- Queries per search scope over the previous 30 days.

Comment: hi amhed,
i need to do auditing on the searches in sharepoint. for example if we search an article in sharepoint, how many times the article is fetched or what are all the article with same name fetched or how many times the same article is being searched... these are the kind of information we need to audit while searching in sharepoint for a particular article... 
i need to know how this is done...help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a slight misunderstanding over what the search webparts do when they provide search results.

All the "fetching" of documents is done when the search crawler runs over the site. This can be audited by importing the stslogs into a database and limiting them down to the username the search crawler uses.

The search results webpart doing the actual search only looks at the index the search crawler creates. Auditing the results a search brings back could be done by a customised search results webpart that stores the url's provided by searches as they are completed, but I am not sure this would provide much value.